# Why activating a conda environment with conda.bat works but without it not?

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-10, conda

I'm trying to figure out why it is possible to active a conda environment with this `conda.bat` script but not when calling `conda activate <environment>`?

Doing it directly with `conda.exe` throws this error:

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.

Calling `conda init cmd.exe` doesn't fix it and it only works with the below script. However, I am not able to crack it. Mainly because I'm not fluent in *batch*.

Could you tell me what is the magic part of this script that makes it work and how can I make it work without it?

```
@REM Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
@REM SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause

@REM echo _CE_CONDA is %_CE_CONDA%
@REM echo _CE_M is %_CE_M%
@REM echo CONDA_EXE is %CONDA_EXE%

@IF NOT DEFINED _CE_CONDA (
  @SET _CE_M=
  @SET "CONDA_EXE=%~dp0..\Scripts\conda.exe"
)
@IF [%1]==[activate]   "%~dp0_conda_activate" %*
@IF [%1]==[deactivate] "%~dp0_conda_activate" %*

@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@IF DEFINED _CE_CONDA (
  @REM when _CE_CONDA is defined, we're in develop mode.  CONDA_EXE is actually python.exe in the root of the dev env.
  FOR %%A IN ("%CONDA_EXE%") DO @SET _sysp=%%~dpA
) ELSE (
  @REM This is the standard user case.  This script is run in root\condabin.
  FOR %%A IN ("%~dp0.") DO @SET _sysp=%%~dpA
  IF NOT EXIST "!_sysp!\Scripts\conda.exe" @SET "_sysp=!_sysp!..\"
)
@SET _sysp=!_sysp:~0,-1!
@SET PATH=!_sysp!;!_sysp!\Library\mingw-w64\bin;!_sysp!\Library\usr\bin;!_sysp!\Library\bin;!_sysp!\Scripts;!_sysp!\bin;%PATH%
@SET CONDA_EXES="%CONDA_EXE%" %_CE_M% %_CE_CONDA%
@CALL %CONDA_EXES% %*
@ENDLOCAL

@IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %errorlevel%

@IF [%1]==[install]   "%~dp0_conda_activate" reactivate
@IF [%1]==[update]    "%~dp0_conda_activate" reactivate
@IF [%1]==[upgrade]   "%~dp0_conda_activate" reactivate
@IF [%1]==[remove]    "%~dp0_conda_activate" reactivate
@IF [%1]==[uninstall] "%~dp0_conda_activate" reactivate

@EXIT /B %errorlevel%
```

So far we've figured out that this script is calling another one `_conda_activate.bat`. It's similar but there is some new stuff too:

```
@REM Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
@REM SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
@REM Helper routine for activation, deactivation, and reactivation.

@IF "%CONDA_PS1_BACKUP%"=="" GOTO FIXUP43
    @REM Handle transition from shell activated with conda 4.3 to a subsequent activation
    @REM after conda updated to 4.4. See issue #6173.
    @SET "PROMPT=%CONDA_PS1_BACKUP%"
    @SET CONDA_PS1_BACKUP=
:FIXUP43

@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@IF DEFINED _CE_CONDA (
  @REM when _CE_CONDA is defined, we're in develop mode.  CONDA_EXE is actually python.exe in the root of the dev env.
  FOR %%A IN ("%CONDA_EXE%") DO @SET _sysp=%%~dpA
) ELSE (
  @REM This is the standard user case.  This script is run in root\condabin.
  FOR %%A IN ("%~dp0.") DO @SET _sysp=%%~dpA
  IF NOT EXIST "!_sysp!\Scripts\conda.exe" @SET "_sysp=!_sysp!..\"
)
@FOR %%A in ("%TMP%") do @SET TMP=%%~sA
@SET _sysp=!_sysp:~0,-1!
@SET PATH=!_sysp!;!_sysp!\Library\mingw-w64\bin;!_sysp!\Library\usr\bin;!_sysp!\Library\bin;!_sysp!\Scripts;!_sysp!\bin;%PATH%
@REM It seems that it is not possible to have "CONDA_EXE=Something With Spaces"
@REM and %* to contain: activate "Something With Spaces does not exist".
@REM MSDOS associates the outer "'s and is unable to run very much at all.
@REM @SET CONDA_EXES="%CONDA_EXE%" %_CE_M% %_CE_CONDA%
@REM @FOR /F %%i IN ('%CONDA_EXES% shell.cmd.exe %*') DO @SET _TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH=%%i not return error
@REM This method will not work if %TMP% contains any spaces.
@FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,100) DO @(
    SET UNIQUE_DIR=%TMP%\conda-!RANDOM!
    MKDIR !UNIQUE_DIR! > NUL 2>&1
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        SET UNIQUE=!UNIQUE_DIR!\conda.tmp
        TYPE NUL 1> !UNIQUE!
        GOTO tmp_file_created
    )
)
@ECHO Failed to create temp directory "%TMP%\conda-<RANDOM>\" & exit /b 1
:tmp_file_created
@"%CONDA_EXE%" %_CE_M% %_CE_CONDA% shell.cmd.exe %* 1>%UNIQUE%
@IF %ErrorLevel% NEQ 0 @EXIT /B %ErrorLevel%
@FOR /F %%i IN (%UNIQUE%) DO @SET _TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH=%%i
@RMDIR /S /Q %UNIQUE_DIR%
@FOR /F "delims=" %%A in (""!_TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH!"") DO @ENDLOCAL & @SET _TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH=%%~A
@IF "%_TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH%" == "" @EXIT /B 1
@IF NOT "%CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER%" == "" @CALL SET "PROMPT=%%PROMPT:%CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER%=%_empty_not_set_%%%"
@CALL "%_TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH%"
@IF NOT "%CONDA_TEST_SAVE_TEMPS%x"=="x" @ECHO CONDA_TEST_SAVE_TEMPS :: retaining activate_batch %_TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH% 1>&2
@IF "%CONDA_TEST_SAVE_TEMPS%x"=="x" @DEL /F /Q "%_TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH%"
@SET _TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH=
@SET "PROMPT=%CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER%%PROMPT%"
```

Comment: If it makes you feel any better about not being fluent in batch, neither is the person who wrote this script.

Comment: @SomethingDark haha true, this is a real mind twister. I can write simple batches but this one is another level :-\

Comment: I'm not familiar with `conda`, but it seems that there's a `conda_activate` program (or maybe script?) that gets triggered when the first argument to this script is `activate` or `deactivate`. Theoretically, any additional arguments would also be passed to `conda_activate` at that time.

Comment: @SomethingDark you're right, this rabbit hole goes deeper and `_coda_activate.bat` is another script. I'll update the question.

Comment: That second script creates a folder in `%TMP%` for logging and then runs `conda.exe %_CE_M% %_CE_CONDA% shell.cmd.exe` followed by any other arguments that the original script received.`%_CE_CONDA%` seems to only be set in Develop Mode, and there's a bit in the first script that unsets `%_CE_M%` if `%_CE_CONDA%` is also not set, so I assume that variable gets automatically set in Develop Mode as well.